# PECL and PHP Build Directory

Tags: php, linux, shell, redhat

I'm trying to install a PECL package, and I received this error. I'm unsure what to do about it, so was hoping someone may be able to offer some help:

```
# pecl install -f ssh2
WARNING: failed to download pecl.php.net/ssh2 within preferred state "stable", will instead download version 0.11.3, stability "beta"
downloading ssh2-0.11.3.tgz ...
Starting to download ssh2-0.11.3.tgz (23,062 bytes)
........done: 23,062 bytes
5 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find build files at '/usr/lib64/php/build'. Please check your PHP installation.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Comment: run (as root):   yum install php-devel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use the pecl, pear, or phpize commands in fedora (redhat based), install the php-devel package:

```
$ yum install php-devel
```